# javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

Tags: java, android, ssl, https

I have:

1. Company.cert.pem
2. ca_cert.pem

and I am trying to perform a ssl connection.

I generated **mykeystore.bks** from these two files(tried any combinations) and use the java code 
from here [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https) - **emmby** responce. But all time I get the next error:

```
12-20 03:04:48.844: W/System.err(2087): javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0x2b6e50: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
12-20 03:04:48.854: W/System.err(2087):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
12-20 03:04:48.854: W/System.err(2087):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:788)
12-20 03:04:48.854: W/System.err(2087):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
12-20 03:04:48.854: W/System.err(2087):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
12-20 03:04:48.854: W/System.err(2087):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
```

*

2. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html

It seems that Android team proposes another approach for this purpose - but for me it's not clear.

Comment: I will be grateful for any advice :(

Comment: Have you found the solution or work around for same?